# 01 number input for date not giving output on system

Tags: c++, mysql

I can't enter 01 into my c++ input, it will return with empty result but when i type other date such as 12 and 11 it does show in the system.

```
string month;
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');
    cout << "Please Enter Month For Example 01 for January:";
    getline(cin, month);
    string search_query = "SELECT DATE(OrderDate), SUM(TotalPrice) FROM order1 WHERE MONTH(OrderDate) like '%" + month + "%' GROUP BY DATE(OrderDate)";
    const char* q = search_query.c_str();
    qstate = mysql_query(conn, q);
```

[DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waCNe.png)

[This is what happen if I enter "01"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ppJ.png)

[This is what happen when I enter "11"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GNG2.png)

[This is when I type "12" it successfully show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuBCx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `LIKE` operator in MySQL, which checks to see if the pattern specified on the right occurs in the string specified on the left.  The pattern "01" probably doesn't occur in the value on the left, since the string on the left should be "1" for January orders, and that doesn't have a "0" in it.

I also imagine that if you type "1" you would actually see all orders from January, October, November, and December since all those months have "1" in them.

Try using something like `MONTH(OrderDate) = 1` instead.

To be more explicit: try changing the line in your program that defined `search_query` to this:

```
std::string search_query = "SELECT DATE(OrderDate), SUM(TotalPrice) FROM order1 WHERE MONTH(OrderDate) = " + month + " GROUP BY DATE(OrderDate)";
```

By the way, for a more robust program, you should also make sure you turn the user-supplied month number into an integer before  adding it to the query string; right now you are letting users insert arbitrary strings into your query, which could be dangerous.

Comment: i see its possible where user can choose the month to view? like in my coding it have user to input which month to view.

Comment: Yes, you can have the user enter the month they want to view.  Then you convert it to an *integer* and then you insert it into your query string with some C++ code like this:  `std::string query = "SELECT ... where Month(OrderDate) = " + std::to_string(month) + " ..."`.  Note that the `...` in the code above represents SQL that you would have to fill in yourself, but you already have that SQL typed in your question so just use that as a starting point.

Comment: can you please type the whole coding for me , i dont know how to utilize this code and not familiar with it especially the std..

Comment: Please see the edit to my question.  I included a line you can just drop into your existing program.  (Delete the existing the line that defines search_query and replace it with mine.)